# Phalcon: How can I use find() with IN() from sql?

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

I've got a Model "Member" and selected (via form) multiple Member-IDs.

Now I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM member WHERE id IN($idsFromForm)
```

Is this possible with Member::find()? If yes then how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Criteria](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model_Criteria.html)

```
$members = Member::query()->inWhere('id', $idsFromForm)->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Member::find(array('member IN ('.$idsFromForm.')'));
```

Comment: I get an error message like: "Column 'id' doesn't belong to any of the selected models (1), when preparing: SELECT [Member].* FROM [Member] WHERE member IN (Array)" But I#ve defined $id public for the Member model and the column in the database has also id as its name

Comment: `Member::find(array('id IN ('.implode(',',$idsFromForm).')'));`